# wordpress help needed. How to display both home.php and index.php?

Tags: homepage

Hey guys i recently created a theme. I want to show home.php when a visitor visit home page but all my blog posts are listed in index.php file. Can someone suggest me how to display index.php i tried http://www.mysiteurl.com/index.php but it redirecting me to http://www.mysiteurl.com/home.php Please advise me. Thanks

Comment: There's no reason you can't use the code from `index.php` in `home.php`.

Comment: Well i'm not trying to use same code. If i rename the home.php file to xxx.php then it calls index.php file. But i need both pages. I mean home.php as index page. I created a nav menu and placed link called blog. When the user click blog link then i wanna show index.php there. This is what i need. By the way thanks for your comment

Comment: if you have home.php as your home page, you can't have index.php as sub page. However, you can have index.php has your home page and blog.php as blog page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're misunderstanding the purpose of `home.php`, which is not *necessarily* to output the *Site Front Page*, but rather to output the *Blog Posts Index*.

In WordPress, the `index.php` is simply the *default fallback* template file, that is used when no other, more-specific template file is available.